# [Blob - FileSaver]Data argument should be a blob instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob, filesaver.js

Here is my problem : i am using angular-file-saver to export my table into an xlsx file, where $document[0].getElementById('exportable').innerHTML is my table inside of a div.

For that, i am creating an object Blob which i pass as parameter to FileSaver.

```
vm.blobData = new Blob([$document[0].getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
    type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8'
  });
var config = {
    data: vm.blobData,
    filename: vm.scoreboardtype + 'scoreboard' + vm.scoreboarddate + '.xls'
  };
FileSaver.saveAs(config);
```

When i execute my code, i have this error : "Data argument should be a blob instance".

Do you have any answers ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just fixed the problem.
FileSaver.saveAs(..), takes parameters now.

```
FileSaver.saveAs(config.data, vm.scoreboardtype + 'scoreboard' + vm.scoreboarddate + '.xls');
```